# R Summarytools Printing Tables

Tags: r, r-markdown, summarytools

I am using the summarytools package in Rmarkdown and knitting into an HTML. The tables look fine, but whenever I print the HTML document, the formatting of the tables (ctable in particular) is off. See picture below

[image]

As you can see, there are those borders within each cell. I believe this has to do with RMD using the default bootstrap.css file, and upon exploration of that file, I found some "@media print" lines. Does anyone have a quick solution to fixing this issue, or would I have to change the underlying bootstrap.css file?

Thanks.

Comment: Unless you find a way to mask these annoying borders with CSS, the best alternative is to stick to the plain text output. At some point in the future the package *might* offer an alternate display where frequencies and proportions are in a single cell, but this would mean less well-aligned content.

Comment: Something else worth trying: convert the html file to pdf using _wkhtmltopdf_ and print the pdf instead. The free _wkhtmltopdf_ tool does help in similar circumstances (converted html to pdf using pandoc displays those borders while this doesn't happen using _wkhtmltopdf_).

Answer (score 2):

> I believe this has to do with RMD using the default bootstrap.css
>   file...

If this is the case, you may try canceling Bootstrap’s CSS with `st_css(bootstrap = FALSE)`.
Also, you may find helpful to include `results = "asis"` to knitr chunk options.
Finally, check out Dominic's "Recommendations for Using summarytools With Rmarkdown" and section about [ctable()](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/summarytools/vignettes/Recommendations-rmarkdown.html#ctable).  Acording to Dominic 'rendering method is preferred' with `method = 'render'`:

````
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
date: "16/06/2020"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: TRUE
    toc_float: TRUE
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(summarytools)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(results = "asis")
```  

```{r summarytools-css, echo = FALSE}
# with summarytools’ CSS we can cancel Bootstrap’s CSS (both are included by default)
# without it odd layout are expected, especially with dfSummary()
st_css(bootstrap = FALSE)
```

```{r summarytools-rmarkdown, echo = FALSE}    
   ctable(tobacco$gender, tobacco$smoker, style = 'rmarkdown')
```  

```{r summarytools-html, echo = FALSE}    
   print(ctable(tobacco$gender, tobacco$smoker), method = 'render')
```
````